# UITextView Delegate Method is not Calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, delegates, uitextview

I have a HTML code which is loading in a UITextView. HTML contains href links.

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange` ;

The above delegate method is not calling when the html contains Arabic texts. But its working fine for English.